# Dynatrace Invoke shell script from Linux server

Tags: dynatrace

Is there a way to create a problem metric in Dynatrace using a shell script that can be executed from the Linux server?

Here, **Problem metric** means,

Let's assume that we are using a shell script to check the status of deployed services on the Linux Server.

Then,

1. That Shell Script should be able to be called by Dynatrace
2. And, based on Shell Script's response, should be able to create Problem.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'problem metric'?

You can create metrics via the [Metric API](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/metric-v2) and Problems via the [Events API](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment-api/events-v2)

You can call either endpoint from a shell script on linux. If there is a OneAgent on the system you could also use an [extension.](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/extensions)

Comment: Hi Pabi, Thanks. I have updated the question. Could you please check that again?

Comment: The easiest way would be with a oneagent extension, that is also the only way you can get dynatrace to actively call the shell script. You could also implement the shell script logic in the extension then though.  

Or you can just schedule the shell script another way, e.g. via cron, an create the problems via the Events API I mentioned, directly from the script.

Comment: Yes Pabi, I thought the same way will try